# Using advanced for loop instead of for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, foreach

I am a bit confused and I would need some clarification. Not too sure if I'm on the right track, hence this thread.

Here is my code that I want to decipher into advanced foreach loop.

```
    int[] arrayA = {3, 35, 2, 1, 45, 92, 83, 114};
    int[] arrayB = {4, 83, 5, 9, 114, 3, 7, 1};
    int n = arrayA.length;
    int m = arrayB.length;
    int[] arrayC = new int[n + m];
    int k = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            if(arrayB[j] == arrayA[i])
            {
                arrayC[k++] = arrayA[i];
            }
        }
    }
    for(int i=0; i<l;i++)
        System.out.print(arrayC[i] + " ");
    System.out.println();
```

So far this is the point where I am stuck at:

```
    int[] a = {3, 8, 2, 4, 5, 1, 6};
    int[] b = {4, 7, 9, 8, 2};
    int[] c = new int[a.length + b.length];
    int k = 0;
    for(int i : a)
    {
        for(int j : b)
        {
            if(a[i] == b[j]) 
            {
                c[k++] = a[i];
            }
        }
        //System.out.println(c[i]);
    }
    for(int i=0; i<c.length;i++)
        System.out.print(c[i] + " ");
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: The value of `i` and `j` will get reset at each iteration. And in order to use `array[index]` form, you cannot use the temporary variables in foreach loop for direct indexing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there

```
for(int i : a)
{
    for(int j : b)
    {
        if(i == j) 
        {
            c[k++] = i;
        }
    }
}
```

With `for(int i : a)` access the elements in the array `a` using `i`.
If `a` is `{3, 8, 2, 4, 5, 1, 6}`, then `i` would be `3,8,2,..` on each iteration and you shouldn't use that to index into the original array. If you do, you would get either a wrong number or a `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

---

Since you want to pick the numbers that are present in both the arrays, the length of array `c` can be `max(a.length, b.length)`. So, `int[] c = new int[Math.max(a.length, b.length)];` will suffice.

If you want to truncate the `0`s at the end, you can do

```
c = Arrays.copyOf(c, k);
```

This will return a new array containing only the first `k` elements of `c`.

Comment: That look reasonable.

Comment: I ran the program with the above, and surprisingly it iterated through the entirety of array 'c', result is 3 common numbers plus the rest of the reserved slots within the array, please see here: 8 2 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

Comment: Yes, because you precreated the `c` array. (It has nothing to do with enhanced for loops)

Comment: Since arrays need predefined length, the best you can do is to take the max of `a` and `b` length. You can read about `ArrayList` if you need arrays whose size is adjustable (there are lots of other options)

Comment: Wicked help there, Sir! Much appreciated

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167993/discussion-between-bence-and-user7).

Answer (score 1):

I would use a `List` and [`retainAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#retainAll-java.util.Collection-). And in Java 8+ you can make an `int[]` into a `List<Integer>` with something like,

```
int[] arrayA = { 3, 35, 2, 1, 45, 92, 83, 114 };
int[] arrayB = { 4, 83, 5, 9, 114, 3, 7, 1 };
List<Integer> al = Arrays.stream(arrayA).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
al.retainAll(Arrays.stream(arrayB).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList()));
System.out.println(al.stream().map(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining(" ")));
```

Outputs

```
3 1 83 114
```

Alternatively, if you don't actually need the values besides displaying them, and you want to use the `for-each` loop (and less efficiently) like

```
int[] arrayA = { 3, 35, 2, 1, 45, 92, 83, 114 };
int[] arrayB = { 4, 83, 5, 9, 114, 3, 7, 1 };
for (int i : arrayA) {
    for (int j : arrayB) {
        if (i == j) {
            System.out.print(i + " ");
        }
    }
}
System.out.println();
```

Comment: Elliott, your comment surely amazed me, though the level of my current knowledge is insufficient to understand it fully. Thanks for the efforts :)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, the first solution you suggested doesn't compile, it runs into an error : List is not generic, it cannot be parameterized with <Integer> , am I missing something?

Comment: Requires Java 8+ and that is `java.util.List`

Answer (score 0):

Temporary variables aren't indices in an array in `foreach` Loop. So in 0th iteration, `i` contains the 0th element of `a`, `j` contains the 0th element in `b`. Your attempt should be like this:

```
int[] a = {3, 8, 2, 4, 5, 1, 6}; 
int[] b = {4, 7, 9, 8, 2}; 
int[] c = new int[a.length + b.length]; 
int k = 0; 
for(int i : a) { 
   for(int j : b) { 
       if(i == j) { 
           c[k++] = i; 
       } 
   } //System.out.println(c[i]);
}
```

Please note your `c[]` array will contain the order maintained in `a[]`.